# Simple EventBridge pattern matching any revision number of a job definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I want to set up a simple trigger for service **B** upon completion of service **A**. More specifically, **B** is a Step Function, and **A** is a Batch job. I am using EventBridge for this but it doesn't seem to support the very simple scenario where I want to match Batch events using a specific job definition for *any revision number*. Below is the event pattern I tried:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.batch"],
  "detail-type": ["Batch Job State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "jobDefinition": ["arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:123456789012:job-definition/my-job-definition:*"],
    "status": ["SUCCEEDED"]
  }
}
```

This doesn't work. It only works if I replace the `"*"` wildcard with a specific revision number, e.g. `my-job-definition:123`.

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2):

**<edit>** Amazon EventBridge announced support for [wildcard filters in rules](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/10/amazon-eventbridge-wildcard-filters-rules/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=offbynone&utm_campaign=Off-by-none%3A%20Issue%20%23250) two days after this question was asked.  Who says AWS isn't responsive to customers?

OP's pattern now matches as intended: `*` is treated as a wildcard.  Docs are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-wildcard-matching).

The original answer is also valid. **</edit>**

---

Use [prefix matching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-prefix-matching) to ignore the revision suffix when matching the ARN:

```json
"jobDefinition": [{"prefix": "arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:123456789012:job-definition/my-job-definition:"}],
```